# Any way to install app to iPhone 4 with Xcode 8 beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

When trying to run app on my iPhone 4, Xcode 8 beta shows me this message:

`This iPhone 4 is running iOS 7.1.2 (11D257), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.`

My app must support iOS 7. I read many answers they say that app build with Xcode 8 beta still can run on iOS 7 devices. So is there a way to install app to iPhone 4 with Xcode 8 beta? Like building the app first, then use a command line to install `.app` file to the iPhone?

Comment: which your deployment target set? iPhone last ios 7.1 that you set deployment target 7.

Comment: My deployment target is 7.0

Comment: you are using itune through install .app file use

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Actually, there is a way. You just need to copy DeviceSupport folder for iOS 7.1 from Xcode 7 to the new one. It's located in:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.1`

I've tried it and it works.

EDIT: If you don't have the 7.1 files anymore, you can find them [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3AdrmeePh3MRlU2bUphYXlBa1E).

Comment: Indeed this works. Be sure to relaunch Xcode after this.

Comment: Can someone copy somewhere those file for share? @petra

Comment: I've updated the answer with the download link. @AlexGuba

Comment: It worked for me also! it did not appear on th elist but manually i write 7.0 and worked.

Comment: Still works like charm with XCode 9.1. Just small remark. There is no 7.1 "Deployment Target" in dropdown list, but you can manually type 7.1.

Comment: I stumble back to this question every year or so, and now have finally found the holy grail: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to debug but only build and put the app on device then you could also use product -> archive to create .ipa file with an adhoc version and then put in on iphone 4 using window -> devices. This works on xcode 8 without any additional files.