# iOS 12.1.2 Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) can't load build into iPhone six

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode10

Xcode : Version 10.0 (10A255)
iPhone6: iOS 12.1.2

My Xcode was running smoothly but after coming back from Christmas holiday I get the following error.

[image]

I searched around and try to rename the following file 12.0 (16A366) to 12.1 but it is still not working. I have also tried to reset the networking on iPhone and reboot the Mac and still it is not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655178/xcode-could-not-locate-device-support-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 10.0 does not support iOS 12.1. Update to Xcode 10.1 to be able to run your project on an iOS device running 12.1. Refer to the following article for more detailed information:

[Xcode and New iOS Versions](https://meandmark.com/blog/2017/12/xcode-and-new-ios-versions/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. update the xCode to lates version
2. download desired version's `DeveloperDiskImage` file(s)

for last one you can download lates files from https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport.

In your case, I had your problem too and because `12.1 (16B91)` version was not available(in the Git link),I download `12.1 (16B91).zip` and copy to `DeviceSupport` dir and the problem was solved.

[image]