# Can we install old Xcode versions on latest mac os versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Can I install **Xcode 10.1** on my mac having OS **Mojave 10.14.6**?

I am have installed Mojave 10.14.6 on my mac. When I tried to install Xcode 8 on the system I got a message like the Xcode version is not supported by the OS.

Is there any document available regarding which all versions of Xcode are supported by different OS versions?

Comment: You'd need to have an OS to match the version supported by the version of Xcode that you're using. Projects written in older versions of Xcode can be opened in the current version, but you'll likely need to squash compiler errors, etc. to get the project up to the current syntax.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for your support. The project which I need to handle is a pretty older one. When I opened the code using Xcode 10.3 it asked me to get 10.1

*****'This workspace has projects that contain source code developed with Swift 3.x. This version of Xcode does not support building or migrating Swift 3.x targets.

Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4.'*****

Comment: Why then you need Xcode 8?

Comment: Sounds like you should try downloading Xcode 10.1, then. Don't get in the habit of picking fights with the compiler LOL. Not sure how big the project is, but you may. be able to migrate it piecemeal into a new project if opening it doesn't get the job done. Try Xcode 10.1.

Comment: If you must use an older Xcode which cannot be installed on your current system, the easier solution will be to install an older MacOS version inside a Virtual Machine on your macOS, and install the older Xcode on it. Eg: If you use Mojave, create a virtual machine of El Capitan and install the older Xcode on it. Use it to compile or migrate [if possible] your old code and work on it directly on your machine. You can do it with VM Ware for MacOS and Apple MacOS license permits you to create a VM and reinstall old versions and use both simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't install too older Xcode versions on the current MacOS versions, you can only install the most recent Xcode versions.

But you need Xcode 8 (and I think it runs on El Capitan).

**There is a good solution:**

Considering you must use an older Xcode which cannot be installed on your current system (*I have the same situation, which you posted the Xcode Swift3 message*) , the easier solution is to install an older MacOS version inside a Virtual Machine on your current macOS, and install the older Xcode on it.

*Eg: If you use Mojave, create a virtual machine of El Capitan and install the older Xcode 8 on it. Use it to compile or migrate [if possible] your code to current/newer Xcode syntax, or keep working on it using the older Xcode directly inside the VM on your current MacOS Mojave machine.*

**How to do it:**

You can do it with VM Ware Fusion for MacOS. The good news is that Apple MacOS **license permits** you to create any VM and reinstall older MacOS/OSX versions inside the current version, and use both the older and the current simultaneously.

You can download any older official MacOS version installations freely from Apple Support, and install the downloaded DMG image right on VMWare, very easy.

---

Here is the Apple Support download link for MacOS installs, scroll down the page and click "**load more results**" button until you find the needed MacOS version (Sierra, El capitan, whatever).

https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/macos

VMWare Fusion for MacOS is also free, you can download it here:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=FUS-1111&productId=798&rPId=35313

After downloading, use the MacOS Install DMG on VMware Fusion (which has a wizard and installs the system just by dragging the DMG install file on it)

Since it is a virtual machine, your current Mojave System will remain intact, and El Capitan will run on it like if it was any normal Application. (this is not dual boot, the VM runs like any application on your desktop).

Considering you will choose El Capitan, after installation is completed, go through the normal Xcode installation process inside it, because it will get the correct and corresponding Xcode version for it from Apple. You can download Xcode via the AppStore icon of the El Capitan Virtual Machine.

Thats all.

Comment: Downvote. There is no way to install a DMG file into a VMware Fusion VM. At least not from DMGs in the link provided here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can download Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.14. Xcode 10 is officially supported on macOS 10.14. Xcode 9 and older versions aren't officially supported on 10.14 by Apple.

One thing to keep in mind for iOS development is that if your iOS device is running something newer than iOS 12.1, you won't be able to get the app on the device with Xcode 10.1. See the following question for additional information:

[iOS 12.1.2 Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) can't load build into iPhone six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927290/ios-12-1-2-xcode-version-10-0-10a255-cant-load-build-into-iphone-six)

The site [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com) has a listing of every version of Xcode, the minimum system requirements, and download links.

Comment: It's a pity that Xcode Releases doesn't tell you the _maximum_ system requirements (i.e. the latest version of macOS that it will run on.)