# hundred of warnings after update to Xcode 10.2.1. is it still OK to be published to App store?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I am panic. I am new in programming and in iOS development. Tomorrow I plan to publish my app to the app store for my company. but this morning I update my iPhone to iOS 12.2, and I must update my Xcode to 10.2.1 in order to make Xcode can run my app on my real device.

but I get hundreds of warnings like the image below. Unfortunately I also stuck to downgrade my iOS on my iPhone to be back to 12.1.4. so it seems that I still have to use Xcode 10.2.1 and iOS 12.2 on my iPhone. there are more than 250 warnings on my Xcode:

[image]

even though almost all the warning are:

> warning: public' modifier is redundant for instance method declared in
>   a public extension

I can run my app without issue. but I choose not to fix the warning and leave the **'Conversion to Swift 5 is available'** and also **'update to recommended settings'**

because it will make error to my firebase Pod and I can't run my app. so my question is....

Can I still publish my app to app store and run without issue on the real device of the users ? because I choose not to fix the warning and leave the **'Conversion to Swift 5 is available'** and also **'update to recommended settings'** , but it still worked without issue on my simulator. I am worried apple will reject my app because I don't fix **'Conversion to Swift 5 is available'** and also **'update to recommended settings'**  warning

Comment: The warning about "public" being redundant should not cause any run-time problems.  I can't guess about any others.

Comment: You should archive and try to submit your app, when uploading starts, it validates the build and it is where you will get error of warnings are not tolerable by Apple, if it validates and continue uploading then there should not be a issue with submitting it for review and publishing..
Hope it helps!

Comment: In the future, don't update your build tools the day before you plan to do a release. Such an update requires a full regression test of your entire app to be sure there are no new issues.

Comment: @Rob I still can run the app on iOS 12.2 without upgrade Xcode ? what is the minimum Xcode version ?

Comment: @Rob thank you very much for the info. I am worried that my code no longer valid and not tolerable because of these warnings. I will try to submit it tomorrow.

Comment: @sarah maybe this will help you , I had the same problem. before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655178/xcode-could-not-locate-device-support-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the decision to update Xcode so you could run this on your device, it turns out that this may have been unnecessary. Largely regardless of Xcode version you use, you generally can manually install an app on an device running a more contemporary iOS version. You just won’t be able to run it via the debugger from an older version of Xcode. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044362/1271826, whose basic concepts about installing still apply today.

All of that having been said, the choice of minimum Xcode version *is* dictated by Apple’s App Store guidelines. See [this March 2019 guideline](http://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03202019a) which says that apps must use iOS 12.1 SDK or later. And watch the [Apple Developer News](https://developer.apple.com/news/) feed as these minimum SDK requirements change over time.

Regarding the warnings, they will not be a problem for submission. Apple doesn’t have your source code and has no exposure to what compile-time warnings you got. The thing is that these warnings really are telling you important and helpful stuff about “such and such *might* be a problem”, which is why it’s good to resolve all of them. We can’t comment about which warnings are really important and what’s not without seeing which warnings you received.

But I’d suggest that you:

- Make sure you install a version of Xcode that supports the minimum SDK version outlined in the [Apple Developer News](https://developer.apple.com/news/) feed; and
- Make a good faith effort to address as many of the warnings as time permits.

At the time of writing, [the minimum SDK version is 12.1](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03202019a). But keep an eye on [that feed](https://developer.apple.com/news/), as the minimum requirements are periodically updated, but generally with some advance warning.