# Running xCode in older iOs version (7.1.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working in an App and I am testing it in some devices. I just got an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 and when I tried to run the App, xCode said "Could not locate device support files" and I tried to update the iOS system but this version is the latest (at least for this phone). I checked xCode supported versions and 8.0 is the least I can use.

Is there any way to run my App in this phone? if not... Did I just waste $7USD buying this phone?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to install app to iPhone 4 with Xcode 8 beta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306688/any-way-to-install-app-to-iphone-4-with-xcode-8-beta)

Comment: I'll take a look at it

Comment: iOS 11 comes out in beta in two weeks. Why are you bothering trying to support iOS 7 devices?

Comment: @rmaddy it is a request I got, because I've been testing my Apps in a recent iOS version (a phone which is not mine) so I got this iPhone 4 but I was not expecting this..?