# Could not instantiate class named UILayoutGuide

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ios7.1

I Have an iPhone 4 running IOS 7.1.2, since the Xcode-Beta doesn't Support anything lower than iOS 8, I referred to this Answer on Stack : [Any way to install app to iPhone 4 with Xcode 8 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306688/any-way-to-install-app-to-iphone-4-with-xcode-8-beta)

So I Followed The Steps, then I made a new Project Connected My iPhone But I get this error:
[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAEfm.png)

Keep In mind that it is a stock project. I didn't change anything except the Minimum Deployment version.

Comment: Don’t post screenshots of text, it’s hard to read and not searchable. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: Also... there is no reason to support back to iOS 7. Only a fraction of a percent of all iOS devices are on iOS 7.

Comment: It's Just that developing on the simulator is hard and i have a baseline macbook air so it gets hot when developing.

Comment: so I just tried to go with the iPhone 4 route

Comment: The trouble with doing that is that you lose 5 years worth of updates to iOS by supporting iOS 7. Even iOS 8 was a massive update and added a load of new features and functions.

Comment: anyways can you please help me?

Comment: Have you even checked the docs for UILayoutGuide? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide It was only added in iOS 9. That’s why you will be getting the error. And also a perfect example of what I was saying about supporting iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck **Use Safe Area Layout Guides** option in the File Inspector in Xcode.

You can open the File Inspector by clicking on View -> Utilities -> File Inspector.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I found Out that making the app programmatically without storyboards solves the problem temporarily